# Preview is unavailable until a successful build... Gradle sync taking to much time

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I'm using latest android studio in Linux mint 18 the preview is not showing and gradle sync taking to much time..

Whenever I give build gradle  in terminal after a minute it's showing build failed and giving suggestions run with `--stack trace`

Answer (score 0):

Sync your project with gradles. from:  **File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files**