# Preview is unavailable until a successful build for android studio

Tags: android

My build has been fixed and is successful, but whenever I add text the preview is unavailable. When I practiced C online (hello world) it displayed hello world in the preview, but in Android Studio it won't.

[image]

I also wanted to ask if #include is used in Android Studio because the phrase is highlighted in a light orange color in my android studio.

Comment: you should explain more

Comment: What its trying to delete?

Comment: You would not be able to see the preview if there is an error in the xml file. And you cannot use   #include<stdio.h>....      This is not "c - language"

Comment: What error could be in the xml file

Comment: see the answer here : [possible duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424327/6561930)